# Generate Arabic QR Code

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

In my app I generate a QR name in Arabic and then scan and I use `zxing` library to generate but it seems that `zxing` library doesn't support Arabic language because when I scan the generated name it gives me `????`. What is the solution?

This is my code to generate:

```
 BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text2QR, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500);
 BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
 bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
 imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hintMap = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);

hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 1); /* default = 4 */
hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);

BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text2QR, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, hintMap);
BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to set text encoding.
`Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");`

so, based on your code it should be

`multiFormatWriter.encode(text2QR, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, hints);`

Comment: @MarkMamdouh how do you decode the encoded QRCode ? is it possible the scanner/reader is not support unicode/arabic?

Comment: i tried to read arabic and it worked, but the problem is in generating it